# How to get modified values from dojo table

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a Dojo table with list of key  value pairs. Both fields are editable, once a value is modified i am doing:

```
var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
```

However, the modified value is not picked up only the old value is picked.
I tried the following:

```js
dojo.parser.parse()

dojo.parser.instantiate([dojo.byId("tableDiv")]);
```

but none of them worked. Can any one sugggest a solution for this.

```js
  function getAllItems() {
    var returnData = "";
    //dojo.parser.parse();

    //dojo.parser.instantiate([dojo.byId("tableDiv")]);
    //grid._refresh();
    var items = grid.selection.getSelected();

    function gotItems(items, request) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        var paramName =    grid.store.getValues(item, "paramName");
        var paramValue = grid.store.getValues(item, "paramValue");
        if (returnData == "") {
          returnData = paramName + "&" + paramValue;
        } else {
          returnData = returnData + "#" + paramName + "&"
              + paramValue;
        }                                  document.getElementById("returnData").value = returnData;
        document.getElementById("successFlag").value = "true";
      }
    }

    //Called when loop fails
    function fetchFailed(error, request) {
      alert("Error reading table data");
    }

    //Fetch the data.
    jsonStore.fetch({
      onComplete : gotItems,
      onError : fetchFailed
    });
  }
```

Comment: Provide more code, I just tried it out myself and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Yenj4/. How do you create your grid? How do you detect when a value is modified?

Comment: i have added the code snippeet which i am using currently

Comment: more important to know is: when do you call `getAllItems()`? How do you detect when a value is modified? Maybe you're calling it too early, when the "old" value is still set.

Comment: i am calling it on click of submit button    <s:form method="POST" action="subGrpParams" id="subGrpParamForm" onsubmit='return saveParams()' theme="css_xhtml">...inside SaveParams() i am calling getAllitems()